# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open file

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am getting error as below.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open file `/var/www/vhosts/websites/example.com/temp/1465979640_1.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3639'

My convert command is as below.

```
convert -background none -font /var/www/vhosts/websites/example.com/fonts/arial.ttf -fill 'rgb(86, 0, 109)' -pointsize 100 label:"Test" /var/www/vhosts/websites/example.com/temp/1465979640_1.png
```

Where output image is not there. I want to create new image using font and text.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Try removing the font and pointsize, and setting the fill to `yellow` and writing in the local directory and see what happens... I am suggesting you simplify your command to something like `convert -background blue -fill yellow -pointsize 100 label:"test" a.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried to simplify the command. But no luck. Getting same error.

Comment: Mmmm.. try `convert -size 100x100 xc:red a.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell First of all, Thank you for your answers. When I use your command it is generating red box of 100x100. But can you tell me what is wrong with my command? If I add xc:red in my command it is generating  red box also.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your command/environment. Something is wrong, so I suggest you start with a simple command and gradually add parts of your own till it goes wrong.

Comment: Is the destination directory writeable? It may be owned by the HTTPD user.

Comment: @emcconville I wondered that, but it is actually failing to *read* not write...

Comment: @MarkSetchell The error is in reading image because I am resizing the created image. Actually I am creating image from the text and font but image is not getting created.

Comment: What version are your running? `identify -version`

Comment: Try removing the `-font`, the `-fill` and the `-pointsize` from your command and writing the result in the current directory. If that works, start adding back in the other aspects of your command unit it fails then look carefully at the last thing you added back.

Comment: @MarkSetchell
convert -size 100x100 xc:red /path/to/my/file.png - Working

convert -size 100x100 /path/to/my/file.png  - Not working

Can you tell me what is wrong here? Why I have to include xc: to my command to make it work?

Comment: I suggested you remove the `-pointsize`, `-font` and `-fill` **not** the `xc:`. The `xc:` creates a canvas for you to draw on or colour in, if you don't have that, you don't have an image and there is nothing to write to your image file. Likewise, `label:` creates a piece of canvas with letters on it, so you need one or the other. You didn't tell me your version.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have to remove label and replace it with -draw. Not it is working. Many thanks for all your help and emcconville yours too.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually it was damn new policies that blocked the use of "label" in command.

Comment: Policies seem to be causing many problems... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37962008/2836621