# How to use stdin with caption in ImageMagick

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

My understanding from reading the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption_bestfit) regarding text, is that the `@-` notation reads the contents of standard input.

As such, this should be a fairly straight forward way to render Hello World.

```
printf "Hello\nWorld" | 
convert \
  -size 1280x100 \
  -background '#0000FF10' \
  -density 90 \
  -gravity Center \
  -fill black \
  -font Helvetica \
  caption:@- \
  test.png
```

On OS X 10.11.5 via [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh), this works, using `convert` Version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-3 Q16 x86_64 2016-05-20.

[image]

However on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the identical command does not work, using `convert` Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-06-01. In fact, it renders the stdin operator, literally.

[image]

The only thing I was able to find that remotely looked like this problem on Google was [this article](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28501), dated back in Oct 2015 in which ImageMagick 6.9.2-5 Beta was patched to fix a similar problem.

**QUESTION**: Am I not escaping it properly, is there really a problem in ImageMagick, or is my Linux Distro picking up a historical version of ImageMagick with the bug and I need to [build from source](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php)?

*Much Later After Many Experiments*

**SOLVED ...?** Built ImageMagick 7.0.2 from source on the Ubuntu box and the above command worked as desired. Was there a better solution?

Comment: Sorry, Mark, for not being able to respond sooner -- I had to recreate a fresh environment to try out the original version of ImageMagick, as I had already 'corrupted' by only working environment when "solved" the problem by recompiling from source rather rather than using the package.

Answer (score 5):

No need to build from source.  Just replace @- with "`tee`" :

```
printf "Hello\nWorld" | 
convert \
  -size 1280x100 \
  -background '#0000FF10' \
  -density 90 \
  -gravity Center \
  -fill black \
  -font Helvetica \
  caption:"`tee`" \
  test.png
```

`tee` will execute first and 'process' stdin before completing the convert command.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is down to differences in your `policy.xml` file. There were recent warnings about IM security vulnerabilities ([detailed here](https://imagetragick.com)) and I guess the `policy.xml` file on one of your servers has been made secure and not the other. The affected line in that file is:

```
<!-- <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" /> -->
```

---

Clarifications contributed by question owner:

- The policy file's location is `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`
- The default state in the package distribution is UNcommented out.
- The recommendation posed here is to comment it out.
- This solution did not work for the question owner; your mileage may vary,

---

Further clarification by Mark:

The location of the policy.xml file is not always `/etc/ImageMagick-6`, it is different on different systems - for example on OS X it is under `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick...`.

The sure way to find the `policy.xml` file is to run the following command and realise that ImageMagick expects the `policy.xml` file to be in the same directory as the `delegates.xml` and `coder.xml`:

```
 convert -debug configure logo: null: 2>&1 | grep -Ei "Searching|Loading"
```

Comment: The solution above did not work for me.  By default, the policy line appears uncommented out. It made no difference whether or not I commended out the policy line shown above.  In fact, in my working recompiled version, the line is uncommented.  Thanks, though.