# Pipe STDOUT to an image?

Tags: linux, image, terminal

Recently, I wanted to run a terminal command like "git show <hash>" and save the output to an image, a PNG preferably.

I googled it quite a bit and found some neat tricks, with the import command notably, but nothing that would capture STDOUT and save it as an image.

So, I thought I'd ask the brain trust here on SO. Anyone have a tested and verified solution for Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by "save it as an image"? Does the file contain image information, or are you looking for something that will convert text to an image of the text?

Comment: If you're looking for a tool that does this automatically, it's not a programming question. Try unix.SE or SuperUser.com.

Comment: I meant take the text output that git show a-hash will generate and preserve it as an image, faithfully reproducing all it's gory color and detail.

Comment: `git show` produces text output, not an image. You need a tool that converts text to an image.

Comment: Correct, and I've googled that but not found any viable solutions that work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: LIke I said, the place to ask for tools is SuperUser.com. It's not a programming question. You could write a PHP script that uses the GD/Image functions. But until you actually have some code to show, the question is not appropriate here.

Comment: "This one is for programming, that one is for tools" sounds kinda like BS when I look at Stack Exchange's short descriptions for the two forums. What do tools get programmed with, rocks of one type or another?
"This is the igneous & basaltic programming forum, go ask in the quartz & granite programming forum." har har har.
I asked over there anyway, because why not. 
*shrug*

Comment: It's true that there's some overlap. My general criteria is if you're just going to type a couple of shell commands, or drag and drop a file, it's a tool, not programming.

Comment: And if anyone can use it without having to know the concepts of variables, functions, control structures (if/while/for), etc. then it's clearly not programming. Programmers use text editors, but that doesn't make questions about text editors on-topic here, unless it's specifically related to the process of writing programs.

Comment: If anyone can use it without having to know the concepts of variables, functions, control structures..., etc. then it's clearly something that should be easy. Yet, it isn't. Viz, here we are with no solution.

Comment: It should be easy for people who know how to use image processing tools on Linux. A good place to find them would be unix.stackexchange.com or SuperUser.com.

Comment: If I realized that what I really had was a gimp question and not anything to do with terminal or a command line utility, I wouldn't have asked anywhere on SE. Feel better? You know, there's something to be said for policing the boundaries but at a certain point, it becomes being a jerk. To wit: if this question was truly inappropriate here, a mod would have closed it as off-topic. You? You're just launching assertions. And you're starting to get on my nerves. So either put up, if you have that authority, or shut up. With lots of capital F's added in for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is save output from `git show` to a file, just do.

```
git show <hash>:path/to/image.png > /some/other/path/image.png
```

If you want to see the image, ImageMagick's `display` command allows piping from STDIN. So you could do

```
git show <hash>:path/to/image.png | display
```

Comment: I tried that, it throws a fatal error: Path 'image.png' does not exist in <hash>
  
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, maybe this works on another distro?

Comment: @user3123081 You're supposed to supply the actual path of an image file in your git repository.

Comment: I think Justin doesn't understand what `git show <hash>` does. It shows information about a commit, not the contents of a file.

Comment: `path/to/image.png` must be a file in the commit specified by `<hash>`. @Barmar, no I understand it fine. The `<hash>:<file>`syntax outputs the contents of `<file>` to STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what **git** outputs, but you should be able to adapt this to make a `PNG` image of that text:

```
echo "git result" | convert -fill red -background yellow label:@- a.png
```

[image]

---

An alternative way of achieving the same result is like this:

```
convert -fill red -background yellow label:"$(git show hash)" a.png
```

---

`convert` (or `magick` from v7 onwards) is part of the **ImageMagick** suite installed on most Linuxes and available for macOS and Windows.

Comment: This generates an 18x15 pixel image with yellow background containing the text "@-" and with the filename a.png, not sure where the "git show <hash>" data went.

Comment: Please try applying the answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/37957972/2836621