# What is the correct way to handle apostrophes in text in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, lucee, cfexecute

I have a script that puts together ImageMagick command line commands to do processing on PDF documents.  These end up being extremely long, but this is a representative example of one such command (line returns added for readability:

```
 magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP ( "c:\IMtemp\32.pdf[0]" -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial
 -pointsize 12 -draw "text 535,515 'This is my test text'") "c:\IMtemp\final.pdf"
```

That command works fine.  However, the text is dynamic and comes from user input.  If the user were to include an apostrophe, the command line would end up being:

```
 magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP ( "c:\IMtemp\32.pdf[0]" -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial
 -pointsize 12 -draw "text 535,515 'This is my test text; it's just great'") "c:\IMtemp\final.pdf"
```

This will fail, of course, because the apostrophe prematurely ends the text block.  My first thought was to escape the apostrophe like this:

```
 magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP ( "c:\IMtemp\32.pdf[0]" -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial
 -pointsize 12 -draw "text 535,515 'This is my test text; it\'s just great'") "c:\IMtemp\final.pdf"
```

But that doesn't work.  Instead the apostrophe is ignored, and the text "This is my test text; its just great" appears.  So then I thought maybe I could use an alternative character and tried this:

```
 magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP ( "c:\IMtemp\32.pdf[0]" -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial
 -pointsize 12 -draw "text 535,515 'This is my test text; it’s just great'") "c:\IMtemp\final.pdf"
```

That results in the text "This is my test text; itâ€™s just great", I assume because IM isn't defaulting to UTF-8.  I read in the docs that this can be circumvented by providing codes to IM and tried:

```
 magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP ( "c:\IMtemp\32.pdf[0]" -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial
 -pointsize 12 -draw "text 535,515 'This is my test text; it\u2019s just great'") "c:\IMtemp\final.pdf"

 magick.exe -density 300 -compress ZIP ( "c:\IMtemp\32.pdf[0]" -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial
 -pointsize 12 -draw "text 535,515 'This is my test text; it\x{2019}s just great'") "c:\IMtemp\final.pdf"
```

But these just displayed everything after the backslash as plain text.

I don't care how apostrophes are preserved, as long as whatever is there looks correct enough to be human-readable and professional.  How do I achieve this?

I'm running IM via cfExecute on a Lucee server (running on Windows / IIS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid all issues with escaping and quoting by feeding the annotation text into **ImagMagick** from a file or from `stdin`. So, if you create a file, called say `"annotation.txt"` that contains:

```
Weird stuff with ', @ and ".
```

You can tell **ImageMagick** to read the annotation from that file (using `@filename`) and place it on your image like this:

```
magick -size 640x240 xc:magenta -gravity center -pointsize 32 -annotate -40+90 @annotation.txt result.png
```

[image]

---

Likewise, if you want to pump the annotation into **ImageMagick** from some other command, you can tell **ImageMagick** to read its `stdin` like this:

```
echo "Whatever @ '" | magick -size 640x240 xc:magenta -gravity center -pointsize 32 -annotate -40+90 @- result.png
```

[image]

---

As Fred kindly reminded me in the comments, you would need to ensure your `policy.xml` file permits this. Its location can be found with:

```
identify -list configure | grep CONFIGURE_PATH
```

More discussion about how to edit and security implications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37962008/2836621).

Comment: You have to be sure your policy.xml file permits the use of @.

Comment: Thank you!  I finally got a chance to try this and it solves all of my problems.  I'm not sure where the disconnect was occurring with passing the text in the command line, but this avoids having to find out and cleans up my command considerably.

Answer (score 3):

Curly single quotes works for me in ImageMagick on my Mac OSX Sierra and ImageMagick 7.0.11.3

```
magick -size 500x100 xc:white -fill "#000" -stroke "#062430" -font Arial -pointsize 18 \
-draw "text 30,30 'This is my test text; it’s just great'" x.png
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  So maybe my assumption was incorrect; maybe cfExecute or Lucee is somehow at fault.  Thank you for giving me some additional information to work with.